# Android - Collect String Array items

Tags: android

I want to collect String[] numbers items. an example: This is my code:

```
public class test extends Activity {
    String[] numbers = {
            "4",
            "7",
            "24",
            "77",
            "98"
    };
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String str = "collect String[] numbers items";
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(str);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @android_Muncher it's me BlackMamba

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and clarify your issue. What are you trying to do? And what is not working?

Comment: You want set string array as textview texto? @BlackMamba2

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for my bad English.
I want to make this 4+7+24+77+98=210.
I want to show '210' with textview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(numbers[i])) {
              total += Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
           }
        }
        //String str = "collect String[] numbers items";
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(total);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect.